# How fork() exit(0) and wait(NULL) works?

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to know how this code works

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<sys/wait.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
  
int main() 
{ 
    pid_t cpid; 
    if (fork()== 0) 
        exit(0);         
    else
        cpid = wait(NULL); 
    printf("Parent pid = %d\n", getpid()); 
    printf("Child pid = %d\n", cpid); 
  
    return 0;
```

`(fork()==0)` returns true if we're in the child process. Right?

Then `exit(0)` will terminate the child process.

Then how will `wait(NULL)` return the child pid if we can't enter the `else` case unless we're in a parent process?

Comment: The example in [man 2 wait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) will help your understanding. (**note:** the use of `_exit()` in the child)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fork` function creates a new processes and returns twice: once to the parent and once to the child.

In the child process, `fork` returns 0 so the `if` section runs which calls `exit`.  In the parent process, `fork` returns the child's pid so it enters the `else` section where it calls `wait` which returns the pid of the child once the child exits.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very good website for understand how use fork(), exit() and wait(). You can find a very good diagrams with code example.

`fork`create new processes, which is called child process, which runs concurrently with the process that makes the `fork()` call (parent process).
After a new child process is created, both processes will execute the next instruction following the `fork()` system call. the child process and parent process use the same **PC(Program Counter)**.

Link for understand only fork:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-system-call/

Link for understand fork with wait() and exit():

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wait-system-call-c/

If you don't understand I have GitHub repo where I use fork(), wait() and exit for create Linux Shell:

https://github.com/ClementBolin/Basic_Shell/blob/master/src/prompt/command.c
https://github.com/ClementBolin/Basic_Shell/blob/master/src/prompt/execute_binary.c

Say me if you want to more information or example